# How do I make two nodes mutually exclusive in ortools TSP?

Tags: traveling-salesman, or-tools

I am trying to optimize a machine path by solving the traveling salesman problem using ortools Python. Each node represents a path drawn by the machine, so we want to minimize the travel distance from `end(node n)` to `start(node n+1)`. The only difference between bog standard TSP is that `distance(a, b) != distance(b, a)` because the machine moves while it is visiting each node.

This works very well.

Now I would like to add the option to draw paths in reverse, from end to start. I would duplicate all the paths but in reverse. By drawing some paths backwards we should be able to get a better solution.

How do I tell ortools that it can visit a path or its reversed duplicate, but not both? Is it just `model.AddDisjunction(node1, node2)`?

Answer (score 2):

Please read this part of the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties

Comment: I've read that a bunch of times but didn't get the "mutually exclusive routes" bit. But the code I wound up with is a slightly modified version of the example on that page.

Answer (score -2):

To make the TSP example choose either Node 1 or Node 2, and either Node 3 or Node 4:

```
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(1), manager.NodeToIndex(2)])
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NoteToIndex(3), manager.NodeToIndex(4)])

initial_solution = routing.ReadAssignmentFromRoutes(data["initial_routes"], True)
# print("Initial solution:")
# print_solution(data, manager, routing, initial_solution)

# Set default search parameters.
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
)
```

We can no longer print `initial_solution` which I've set to be all the nodes in order, which is not a valid solution. All the non-duplicate ones in order might be a decent starting point. It appears the `first_solution_strategy` has to be set to be able to drop nodes.

`NodeToIndex` and `IndexToNode` both take and return integers. In my cases the node was always equal to the index, but it must be possible for them to be unequal.

Comment: This is wrong. It should.be nodetoindex and not indextonode.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like `IndexToNode(x) = x` for all indices I care about, which would explain why it works while being incorrect. I could just pass `x` directly? https://github.com/dholth/gcodeopt/blob/master/cvrp.py#L95